# event.which === 13 on iOS?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a text field with no submit button that works fine on desktop browsers – but not when I hit Return on iOS Safari. Why? Is `event.which === 13` not valid on mobile devices? Thanks!

**Template**

```
<template name="searchPool">
    <span class="search">
        <input 
            type="text"
            name="searchDB"
            value="{{ slug }}"
            class="searchFor"
            maxlength="24"
            size="9">
    </span>
</template>
```

**Event**

```
Template.mainHeader.events({
    'keypress input.searchFor': function (event) {
        if (event.which === 13) {
            var searchingFor = event.currentTarget.value;
            Session.set('slug', searchingFor);
            Router.go('pool', {slug: searchingFor, page: 1});
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: The easy and the most robust solution: wrap the input in a form and listen for the submit event.

Comment: I agree with Juhana, use a form. Otherwise, do something like `alert(event.which)` to see what it contains when you use a mobile device. Perhaps `return` on mobile devices differ from `return` on ordinary PCs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Juhana and @peppe-l-g! This works:

**Template**

```
<template name="searchPool">
    <span class="search">
        <form class="seachDbForm">
            <input type="text" name="searchDB" value="{{ slug }}" class="searchFor" maxlength="24" size="9">
        </form>
    </span>
</template>
```

**Event**

```
Template.mainHeader.events({
    'submit .seachDbForm': function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var searchingFor = event.target.searchDB.value;
        Session.set('slug', searchingFor);
        Router.go('pool', {slug: searchingFor, page: 1});
    }
});
```